# Derivative of a function along a path

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having problems visualizing and understanding the chain rule for the derivative of a function along a path. i.e $$\frac{df(r(t))}{dt}=\nabla f(r(t))\cdot r'(t)$$

My thinking is that this result should be zero as $\nabla f$ is an orthogonal vector and $r'(t)$ is a tangent vector to the surface. I know I am wrong but I can't see how? If anyone can enlighten me I'd appreciate it.

Comment: do a bunch of examples in the plane. If $f(x,y)$ and $r = (x(t), y(t))$ are simple enough, you can readily calculate both sides of your equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* the path parametrized by $\vec{r}(t)$ happens to be a contour of $f$, *then* (as you say) $\nabla f$ will be perpendicular to the curve and therefore perpendicular to $\vec{r'}(t)$.  Therefore, the derivative will be zero.  Another way to see this is that $f$ is (by definition) constant along a contour, thus (again) the derivative will be zero.

More generally, however, $\vec{r}$ may parametrize some arbitrary path, not necessarily a contour.  That is when the formula is relevant.